# I am trying to find xpath for checkbox in a table column

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find the Xpath for a checkbox and then click it using my Python Webdriver script.
The checkbox is in a column in a table.  The text for the checkbox is in another column.
The text is DM.  I want to click the checkbox which has the text value DM.
I don't want the checkbox which has the text value ceb07_14_1504_06_52

I need some help to get the Xpath please.

The HTML is:

```
    <table cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
<colgroup>
<tbody>
    <tr class="GAT4PNUFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
    <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUGG GAT4PNUHG">
    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-139" style="outline-style:none;" tabindex="0">
        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUGG">
    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-140" style="outline-style:none;">
        <span class="linkhover" title="ceb07_14_1504_06_52" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">ceb07_14_1504_06_52</span>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUGG">
    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-141" style="outline-style:none;">
        <span class="" title="Selenium Webdriver added datamap" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">Selenium Webdriver added datamap</span>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUGG GAT4PNUBH">
    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-142" style="outline-style:none;">
        <span class="" title="" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;"/>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="GAT4PNUEH GAT4PNUMG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
    <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUFH GAT4PNUHG GAT4PNUNG">
    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-139" style="outline-style:none;">
        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUFH GAT4PNUNG">
    <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-140" style="outline-style:none;">
        <span class="linkhover" title="DM" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">DM</span>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUFH GAT4PNUNG">
    <td class="GAT4PNUEG GAT4PNUFH GAT4PNUBH GAT4PNUNG">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried //input[@type="checkbox" and tabindex="-1"]
I have tried //input[@type="checkbox"]
This will be no good because the table could grow as data is added.

I have also tried:

```
datamaps_checkbox_element = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/input')
datamaps_checkbox_element.click()
```

regards, Riaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have some errors your html:

```
line 39: the "td" tags must be closed
line 41: you must close the "colgroup"
```

btw:

```
content="//span[text()='DM']/../../..//input"
            try:                
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda s: s.find_element_by_xpath(content).is_displayed())

        except TimeoutError:
            logging.fatal("Timeout occurred trying to search content["+content+"]")
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(content).click()
```

the try/except block is needed only if you have more than one "find_element_by_*" in your code

Regards
Claudio

Answer (score 2):

With the text based xpath search

```
//span[text()='DM']/../../..//input
```

I always suggest to use css instead of xpath if possible.

For the first checkbox

```
.GAT4PNUEG.GAT4PNUGG.GAT4PNUHG>div>input
```

2nd checkbox

```
.GAT4PNUEG.GAT4PNUFH.GAT4PNUHG.GAT4PNUNG>div>input
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to select the element with text `DM` why don't you use xpath with `title='DM'`

```
//span[contains(.,'DM')]
```

or checkbox as

```
//span[contains(.,'DM')]/../preceding::input[1]
```